# Importing a User's friend data into an iOS app from facebook

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have just stumbled across this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23417356/facebook-graph-api-v2-0-me-friends-returns-empty-or-only-friends-who-also-use-m) which indicated that as of facebook V2.0 API we can't get friends data from a user.

I understand this for game invites, etc. But I was wondering if there was any way at all to import the data into the app's local database. Our app is kind of like a diary of each friend, so we basically need a skeleton of data entry for the user.

This functionality is a central focus of the app, without getting a local, workable copy of their friends list things will be difficult indeed. Is there any workaround out there?

Given our app is so "facebook friends" orientated, is it possible to implement more of it outside of ios scope or anything? I know I am probably clutching at straws here but I thought I would ask for suggestions.

Does anyone know if linked-in has a similar restriction?

Does anyone know if it is possible to get the information of one friend at the user's request?

Comment: You can only get friends that are also using the app.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can get all your user's friend information (even the ones who don't use the app)

```
//Configure the request
NSString *fbToken = [FBSession activeSession].accessTokenData.accessToken;
NSString *fbURL = @"https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?access_token=%@";
NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",fbURL, fbToken]];
NSURLRequest *friendRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:URL];
//Send the request
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:friendRequest queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {

if (!connectionError) {

    NSDictionary *friendData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:nil];

    NSLog(@"friend data = %@",friendData);

    //Grab friends ID (or whatever else you want, just replace dic[@"id"]] with dic[@"name"]] or something

    NSMutableArray *friendIDArray = [NSMutableArray array];

        for (NSDictionary *dic in friendData[@"data"]) {

            [friendIDArray addObject:dic[@"id"]];
        }

    }

}
```